# Running systemd-tty-ask-password-agent without sudo

Tags: sudo

We have user home directories that are automatically mounted via autofs through LDAP. Every time a user wants to `cd` into their home directory, we get an error message as follows: `Please enter password with the systemd-tty-ask-password-agent tool!`. However, running `systemd-tty-ask-password-agent --query` in user mode will return a "Not querying (...), **lacking privileges**" error. Is there no way we can have systemd-tty-ask-password-agent to run **without** sudo?